# determining paths between root and terminal vertices?

Tags: r, graph, terminal, nodes, igraph

I've obtained some code (courtesy of you kind folks) that finds my root and terminal nodes in a large graph (n=266) that represents lineage of melting and fracturing pieces of floating ice in the Arctic:

```
vattrib_df$inst[is.na(vattrib_df$motherinst == TRUE)]

roots = which(sapply(sapply(V(g),
                    function(x) neighbors(g, x, mode = 'in')), length) == 0)

terminals = which(sapply(sapply(V(g),
                    function(x) neighbors(g, x, mode = 'out')), length) == 0)
```

When I enter 'roots' and 'terminals' into the console I get the observation names of 6 and 11 observations, respectively.

What I'm looking to do now is calculate the path of nodes between each of these combinations. For example, could I make a matrix out of this data? I'm very new to R, so it's still very difficult for me to have the foresight to know how to approach these questions in coding terms.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g <- random.graph.game(10, .15, directed = TRUE)

roots = which(sapply(sapply(V(g),
  function(x) neighbors(g, x, mode = 'in')), length) == 0)
terminals = which(sapply(sapply(V(g),
  function(x) neighbors(g, x, mode = 'out')), length) == 0)
roots
# [1] 2 4
terminals
# [1] 1 5 8
(paths <- lapply(roots, all_simple_paths, graph=g, to=terminals))
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# + 2/10 vertices, from 1951039:
#   [1] 2 5
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# + 4/10 vertices, from 1951039:
#   [1] 2 6 3 8
# 
# [[1]][[3]]
# + 5/10 vertices, from 1951039:
#   [1]  2  6  3 10  8
# ......
```

Check out `?all_simple_paths` and maybe also `?all_shortest_paths`.